# stanford cs101 javascript error in week 5

Tags: javascript

so i have been slowly working through cs101, first question of week 5 block 4 has me stumped.

so the idea is im supposed to be writing psuedo accurate javascript to determine the number of names starting with A and B in a 2000 entry csv of baby names, im 99% sure i have written the correct code but keep getting returned "unexpected token "{" " i have tried removing all curly brackets one by one which just produces errors obviously and have no idea what i have done wrong, please help.

```
    table = new SimpleTable("baby-2010.csv");

count1 = 0;  // A count
count2 = 0;  // B count
for (row: table) {

  if (row.getField("name").startsWith("A") {
    count1 = count1 + 1;
  }

  if (row.getField("name").endsWith("B") {
    count2 = count2 + 1;
  }

}
print("A count:", count1);
print("B count:", count2);
```

Comment: `for (row: table)` is not correct way to loop in JavaScript.

Comment: Also `if (row.getField("name").startsWith("A")` and `if (row.getField("name").endsWith("B")` both are missing a closing `)`

Comment: `for (row: table) {` is not valid ECMAScript. Whether a syntax error is thrown at the `:` or `{` likely depends on the parser.

Comment: WTF is _"psuedo accurate javascript"_

Comment: yea idk this course is weird a lot of actual js things dont work and it makes up a lot of things that are not remotely a part of js, i have done everything exactly as the lecture says to and just cant fathom why im getting this error... used the same syntax in the previous question and had no issue whatsoever

Answer (score 0):

all good, VLAZ had the correct solution, both if statements were missing a closing ).

thanks heaps guys

Comment: Even if it's an answer to your own question, I think you should be more specific and write down the full code for the two parts that fixed your issue.

Answer (score -2):

use `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` instead of `startsWith` and `endsWith`

```
  if (row.getField("name").indexOf("A") === 0) {
    count1 = count1 + 1;
  }

  if (row.getField("name").lastIndexOf("B") === row.getField('name').length) {
    count2 = count2 + 1;
  }
```

You could also use a regex test for `/^A/` or `/B$/`